# Sometimes MediaFailed event fired for WPF MediaKit

Tags: wpf, wpf-mediakit

MediaFailed event fired twice from time to time, my xaml is as below:

```
<controls:MediaUriElement Name="videoMedia" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 20 20 5" VerticalAlignment="Center"
 DeeperColor="False" VideoRenderer="EnhancedVideoRenderer" UnloadedBehavior="Stop"
 MediaOpened="videoMedia_MediaOpened" MediaFailed="videoMedia_MediaFailed"
/>
```

the information for first MediaFailedEventArgs.Exception is as below:
Message  "The download of the specified resource has failed"
Source   "DirectShowLib-2005"
StackTrace:

```
"  at DirectShowLib.DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 hr)\r\n   at WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.MediaPlayers.MediaUriPlayer.oldOpenSource()"
```

Second exception is as below:
Message  "Unspecified error"
Source   "DirectShowLib-2005"
StackTrace:

```
"   at DirectShowLib.DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 hr)\r\n   at WPFMediaKit.DirectShow.MediaPlayers.MediaUriPlayer.OpenSource()"
```

Note: because my application is target for .NET 4.0, I change the source code and rebuild in my local machine, the source code change is:
change D3DRenderer.cs from
D3DImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, backBuffer, true);
to 
D3DImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, backBuffer);

Comment: It's a bug, that the `MediaFailed` event is fired twice, it should be fired just once.

Comment: How do you set the `MediaUriElement.Source`? I guess it's Uri and the error is that the download has failed.